# str has no attribute write

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pickle

I am getting this error:

```
self.write = file.write
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

What I want to do is dump `m` into file-name that user has entered in an entry...and this is not the whole code please say to import tkinter etc.

```
def send(self):
    fl=(t1.get())
    m=(t2.get())       
    x=open("DATABASE.dat",'rb')
    l=pickle.load(x)
    x.close()
    if fl in l:
        box.showinfo("SEND","MESSAGE SEND")
        x=open(fl+".dat","wb")
        pickle.dump(x,m)
        x.close()

    else:
        box.showerror("ERROR","USER DOES NOT EXIST")
```

ERROR is:

Comment: Which line in the code you posted is producing the error? Is there a stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't cause the error you say it does.

Regardless, the error is telling you exactly what the problem is: you're referencing the "write" method on a string. Maybe you *think* you're referencing it via an open file object but you are *actually* referencing it on a string.

Without seeing your code we can't debug it any further, but it's highly likely you're reusing a variable to be both a filename and an open file.

Comment: thanks buddy sorted it out it just a silly mistake i made it should be like pickle.dump(m,x)...
what i did is pickle.dump(x,m)....